# How to custom spring security i18n with param

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I build a spring boot security app .

and  in the web

```
${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}
```

in message.properties there is :

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials={0} username and password not correct !
```

How can i config the above param **{0}** ?

Comment: What do you mean by "config the above param {0}"? Why replace the `{0}` with what is needed in `message.properties` ?

Comment: @miensol  I add a Interception of  login attempts . That is when login failure 10 times , the custom ip will be blocked . `{0} ` means left times of failure .So `badCredentials={0} username` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials is used by Spring (AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider) to throw an BadCredentialsException with that message:

```
throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials",
                "Bad credentials"));
```

There is no way to provide a parameter to the exception constructor directly. But your goal - show failed login attempts - is quite easy to achieve. You can easily fix your display logic to display the login attempts counter from the session next to, or instead of BadCredentialsException message. This is probably the best approach because you need session data (failed attempts counter) not available in the AuthenticationProvider throwing the exception.